# R if else for write.table if character variable has value

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Say, I have a data frame which I need to save with different suffixes, given a value for the suffix variable or not.

The suffix value is defined in the `keyvalue` variable, which is of type character.

```
keyvalue ="_TRP-1"
outdir= "/user/path/results/"
sample= "ADAS"
```

And I need to write my `output` file to the `outdir` directory using an `if loop` with the condition:  if `keyvalue` is not equal to `na` or `else`

This is what I tried,

```
if (!is.na(keyvalue)){
    write.table(output, paste(outdir, sample, keyvalue,"_scores.tsv", sep=""), sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)

}else{
  write.table(output, paste(outdir, sample,"_scores.tsv", sep=""), sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)

}
```

In the end, I want to have a data table/ file named, `ADAS_TRP-1_scores.tsv` given a `keyvalue` otherwise a file named, `ADAS_scores.tsv`. However, the above lines are not generating any tables as well as error messages, any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be extremely helpful if you could provide the error message.
But on a first look this has two issues:

1. You are using `sample_id` below, but only `sample` is defined.
2. Your `outdir= "/user/path/results"`-character lacks a `/` at the end.

So the code would be:

```r
write.table(
  output,
  paste( sample, keyvalue,"_scores.tsv", sep=""), sep="\t",
  row.names=F, quote=F
)
```

Comment: The `paste` will not ignore rather it will add an `NA` to the filename. However, my script is working now, my bad,  the script I had was missing the `/` (forward slack). With that fix the above lines in my post work. In any case, I have accepted your answer, as your input was critical. Thanks

Comment: True, my bad. I will adjust the answer in case someone else reads this